# How can I achieve a new array with columns from another array's rows? [php]

Tags: php, csv, parsing, pivot

I have this kind of array:

```
2020-01; Starter1; 11,4%
2020-01; Starter2; 6,9%
2020-01; Starter3; 9,5%
2020-01; Starter4; 11,1%
2020-02; Starter1; 5,8%
2020-02; Starter2; 5,8%
2020-02; Starter3; 10,0%
2020-02; Starter4; 6,4%
```

I need to obtain this:

```
Year;    Starter1; Starter2; Starter3; Starter4
2020-01; 11,4%;     6,9%;     9,5%;     11,1%
2020-02; 5,8%;     10,0%;     10,0%;    6,4%
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It would really helpful if you show the result of `var_dump` or `print_r` method on the array.

Comment: @ADyson I do not know from where to begin. I have a txt file containing that type of content, which I read it using ``` fgets ``` and eventually explode each row with delimiter ``` ; ``` . I need to include this data into an google chart and I need to have that kind of array structure.

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour it's just an array, simple as that, I don't think you need the dump, or print_r. My problem is how to restructure that array into a new one, basically to create a new multidimensional array with columns from the original array's rows, as shown in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), as it CSV, then just assign the first and second columns as the array keys, normalising it and then once you have that you can loop over it and built your desired result.

So aiming to make this structure:

```
Array
(
    [2020-01] => Array
        (
            [Starter1] => 11,4%
            [Starter2] => 6,9%
            [Starter3] => 9,5%
            [Starter4] => 11,1%
        )

    [2020-02] => Array
        (
            [Starter1] => 5,8%
            [Starter2] => 5,8%
            [Starter3] => 10,0%
            [Starter4] => 6,4%
        )

)
```

You can loop over to make:

```
Year;    Starter1; Starter2; Starter3; Starter4
2020-01; 11,4%;    6,9%;     9,5%;     11,1%;    
2020-02; 5,8%;     5,8%;     10,0%;    6,4%;
```

Like:

```
<?php
$str = '2020-01; Starter1; 11,4%
2020-01; Starter2; 6,9%
2020-01; Starter3; 9,5%
2020-01; Starter4; 11,1%
2020-02; Starter1; 5,8%
2020-02; Starter2; 5,8%
2020-02; Starter3; 10,0%
2020-02; Starter4; 6,4%';

// normalise and group data
$result = [];
foreach(str_getcsv($str, "\n") as $row){
    $row = array_map('trim', str_getcsv($row, ";"));
    $result[$row[0]][$row[1]] = $row[2];
}

// loop over to specification
echo 'Year;    Starter1; Starter2; Starter3; Starter4'.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($result as $year => $row) {
    echo $year.'; ';
    foreach ($row as $key => $col)
        echo $col.";".str_repeat(' ', (($v = strlen($key)-(strlen($col)-1)) && $v > 0) ? $v : 0);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/11VaW

Comment: np, it should work as long as all cols are filled and data (date) is in order, if you want something more robust you should parse each line into a db and then query the db, or your need to implement sorting

Comment: though could also do https://3v4l.org/HIBil but as you can see it might just be easier to plop all data in a db